Need to turn on a load with a GPIO that must be high at power up. Is my schematic correct?
I need to use the only GPIO left in my microcontroller to switch on a load. Unfortunately that GPIO needs to be pulled high at the moment of powering up the microcontroller, so i have a pull up resistor.
I want to turn on the load pulling the GPIO low, to avoid issues at power up the system (both load and microcontroller are powered by the same source).
On top of that, the  microcontroller works at 3.3V and the load at 5V
I came up with this schematic, but i am a noob and i have the feeling that i am missing something...

(the selection of the mosfet is because i have a bunch of them).
As i understand it. At power up, the GPIO is high (must be), Q1 is on, bringing the gate of Q2 low and the load off. Only when GPIO turns low, Q1 gets off bringing Q2 gate high and switching the load on. I didn't add a pull down resistor to Q2 to avoid creating a voltage divider, and because i understand it might be not necessary.
Does this have any chance to work? Is there a better way to do it that doesnt involve more parts or ICs? (i am in a budget)
Note that i dont need to switch on/off fast, this is to switch a real device a couple of times a day.
edit:
Thank you for the comments, as explained in the comment below, indeed the grounds will be connected. I will try to do this instead.

now when GPIO goes low, the drain of Q10 goes low and Q9 turns on connecting 5v to the load (connector)

What is the load? E.g. how much current does it draw and is it inductive (such as a relay)?

the load is a small HDMI audio extractor. It has a buck converter and a LDO at its power connection. Doesn't need much current, less than 0.5A. It is meant to be powered by a USB charger.

i was thinking if it would be better to add a pull down resistor to Q2 (much weaker than R2) to make 100 sure there are no glitches at power up....

How are the sequence power up of the voltages 3.3V and 5V?

the whole sytem is powered with a single 15VDC power supply. There is a buck converter bringing that down to 5V - the load gets powered directly from that - then an additional LDO that takes those same 5V to 3.3V - the microcontroller gets powered from that -.

Wanted to add: maybe i am overstimating the potential issue of the load getting power briefly before the 3.3V switch it off. I am relatively confident the device will not get damaged or something.

Switching the GND pin of your load ("a small HDMI audio extractor") may not be an good idea or work as well as you hope. It's likely to "bootleg" GND from one or more of its signal inputs or outputs and remain switched on when you want it to be off.

It looks like that will work.
When looking at it in isolation of what you actually want to do, which depends on what connections the switched device has and where.
In most cases it makes little to no sense disconnecting the ground lead from a device that connects the
ground to multiple devices through cables.
Most often you end up that the grounds are connected together via other routes, so the FET switching the ground wire does actually nothing as the device connects the ground back to supply via another route, sometimes an unintended route, such as data wire, possibly damaging something.
But the FET circuit itself looks fine.

I knew I was missing something Thank you both. Sure there will be signal connections with their grounds coming back from the HDMI extractor, actually the purpose is to tap its i2s outputs and process them in the main board, that is a DSP. Seems that i am going back to the initial plan, use a logic level shifter with no inversion and use a P-mosfet to switch the high side, leaving the ground alone. will add an edit to the original post with the schematic
